# Batch text replace

Tags: windows-7, text-editors, text-editing

I have a text file full of links like this . Links are from different sites so they don't follow same structure

```
http://somesite1.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cats.jpg
http://somesite2.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/dogs.jpg
http://www.somesite3.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/elephants.png
http://www.somesite4.com/files/images/horses.jpg
http://www.somesite5.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/birds.png
```

I want to replace their link with mine so the output is like this . Any way to select text from http to last occurrence of / per line ? Windows 7 PC . Notepad++ and Sublime Text 2 installed . Can install any other software if needed .

```
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cats.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/dogs.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/elephants.png
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/horses.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/birds.png
```

Comment: Yes, use a RegEx search and replace capable text-editor.

Comment: What OS, what text editors do you have? What did you try?

Comment: Windows 7 . Notepad++ and Sublime text 2 . I can install any software if needed . Haven't tried anything . No idea how to proceed.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 . What would be the search pattern in this case ?

Comment: There's plenty of RegEx tutorials online, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing . I don't know what to do . I am reading these two but cant understand how to apply in my case .


    http://www.rexegg.com/regex-uses.html#textsearch
    http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Notepad++:

- Open Notepad++.
- Load your file of URLs.
- Open up the Find/Replace dialog.
- Ensure Regular Expressions is enabled, and that ". matches new line" s NOT.
- "Find what:" `http://.*/`
- "Replace with:" `http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/`
- Hit "Replace All".
- Profit.